# Which effect has the extends constraint with a equality sign in a generic type definition?

Tags: typescript

I've seen this `extends` syntax:

```
export type MyType<Data extends Base = Base> = { data: Data }
```

What does the usage of `Base = Base` do?

The TypeScript [documentation about generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Default generic parameter - docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)

It allows you to call `MyType` without generic parameter.

```js
type Base = { tag: 'Base' }

export type MyType<Data extends Base = Base> = { data: Data }

// type WithArgument = {
//     data: {
//         tag: 'Base';
//         name: 'John';
//     };
// }
type WithArgument = MyType<{ tag: 'Base', name: 'John' }>

// { data: Base; }
type Result = MyType
```

Pure js analogy:

```js
const myType = (arg = { tag: 'Base' }) => arg
const result = myType() // { tag: 'Base' }
```

This `Data extends Base = Base` means:

1. Data should extends Base
2. If Data is not provided, use Base by the default

This is how it can be splited into two parts:

1. `Data extends Base`
2. `Data = Base`

You should not read `Base = Base` separately from `extends word`

Answer (score 0):

It's default value of generic. For ex.:

```js
type MyType<Data extends Object = String> = { data: Data }

let test: MyType = {data: 'test'}; // Same as MyType<string>

console.log(typeof test.data); // prints string

let test2: MyType<Number> = {data: 5}; 

console.log(typeof test2.data); // prints number
```